# How to make a GWT script that can be injected into another page?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-extension

How can I make a GWT app that'll run when I inject the .js file into another page? I'm making a Chrome content script. Is there a linker that simply generates a portable, standalone, js file?

When I use the single script linker and inject the resulting nocache.js file, the page is just blank.

Comment: Not a GWT expert, but you should be able to compile GWT to JS and then inject the result. My suggestion is to first try injecting a simple JS file.

Comment: Also when you say "inject" do you mean you are injecting the GWT JS into the page *after* it loaded? Because if you are then it probably wouldn't work, because the boot strap code is wouldn't run.

Answer (score 2):

The Single Script Linker is the right way to go here. You need to make sure that your GWT compilaton only emits one compilation result.  Since you are buidling for chrome you need to set the user agent variable to:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Have you tried to compilate pretty and see in the javascript debugger what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .nocache.js extension to load the rest of the JavaScript, you'll have multiple artifacts on the server but that is for the best.

If you need to call into the javascript, use **[GWT Exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/)** to define what functions are exported to javascript, and you can use JSNI for the rest.